# Structural breaks in data set tried using bp. breakpoints function but didn't work

Tags: r

This is my data:

- https://www.policyuncertainty.com/media/All_Daily_Policy_Data.csv
- https://economicpolicyuncertaintyinchina.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/2/7/122762465/cnepu_daily_14_apr_2020_updated.xlsx

My task is to find (if there are any) structural breaks in both data sets.

I tried to use breakpoints function with

```
library(strucchange)

bp.us_epu<- breakpoints()
```

but it doesn't work.
Can someone help?

Comment: Function `breakpoints` needs arguments, starting with a model formula. Please read `help('breakpoints')`.

Comment: well, this is my code, but somehow it doesn't work bp.us_epu <- breakpoints(us_epu ~ 1)
summary(bp.us_epu)

Comment: You have links to 2 different data sets and `us_epu` is in neither of them.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention us_epu is the data set from the first link, www.policyuncertainty.com/media/All_Daily_Policy_Data.csv